# How to have the correct char encoding using information from a external database?

Tags: r, character-encoding, dbi

In my database i have this value in a field of a table

> CIÓN

an accent in vowel "O", when i get information from the table into R through a connection DBI, the character is displayed wrongly in this way

> CI\xe0N

I've tried define others encodings like "latin1" and "windows-1252" but all of them have been failed.

code try:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "{MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver}",
                 Server = "{server}", database = "database", UID = "user",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("password"),
                 Port = "port"
                 , encoding = "windows-1252")
                  # , encoding = "latin1") #I've tried "latin1" too                         
               # , encoding = "UTF-8") #I've tried "UTF-8" too   

sql_r<- "select field  from table"
res <- dbGetQuery(con,sql_r)
```

Tries of encodings:

```
    LATIN1         display -> IàN
    LATIN2         display -> IŕN
    WINDOWS-1252   display -> IàN
    UTF-8          display -> I\xe0N   (is the default display)
```

I will share sessionInfo() (locale) and info of the table in the server SQL if that helps

```
sessionInfo()
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.utf8
```

collation of the table in the DB.

`utf8mb3_general_ci`

Comment: `Ó` (U+00D3,  *Latin Capital Letter O With Acute*) has code `0xe0`in any  encoding from the following list: ['cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp857', 'cp858']… I'd try connecting using `'cp850'` (US & Western Eu).

Comment: omg, thank you, I coudn't find the answer to this in any place, but this is the right answer.
(I don't know why but i can't put this as "solution", stackoverflow doesn't show me the option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. The following `R` code could help detecting right value for parameter `encoding` in the `dbConnect` function:

```
x <- "CI\xe0N"
c(x, uchardet::detect_str_enc(x))
# [1] "CI\xe0N" "IBM852"
```

In fact, your particular mojibake case for `Ó` (U+00D3,  *Latin Capital Letter O With Acute*) meet more encodings (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
['Ó'.encode(e).decode('LATIN1') for e in ['cp775','cp850','cp852','cp857','cp858']]
# ['à', 'à', 'à', 'à', 'à']
['Ó'.encode(e).decode('LATIN2') for e in ['cp775','cp850','cp852','cp857','cp858']]
# ['ŕ', 'ŕ', 'ŕ', 'ŕ', 'ŕ']
```